# About setUserInteractionEnabled UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, setuserinteractionenabled

I'm newbie in iOS and i have a problem with `setUserInteractionEnabled` as:
 I have a object extend from **UIImageView** like:

```
@interface CustomImageView : UIImageView

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *sNameImage;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *sID;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float nPointX;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float nPointY;

-(void)setPoint:(NSString *)sPoint;
```

Then when i add it to **UIView** like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < self.arrCustomImageView.count; i++)
{
    CustomImageView *cuiv = [self.arrCustomImageView objectAtIndex:i];
    NSData *data = [self readDataFromFile:cuiv.sNameImage];
    if(data != nil && data.length > 0)
    {
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        CGRect r = CGRectMake(cuiv.nPointX, cuiv.nPointY, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        [cuiv setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE]; /*or NO i tried all*/
        [cuiv setImage:image];
        cuiv.frame = r;
        [self addSubview:cuiv];
        [image release];
        image = nil;
    }
}
```

Then in `touchesBegan`, i still catch event when touch on it (i still receive log when touch it) :|

Then source touchBegan method:

```
UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
for (UIView *aView in [self subviews])
{
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([aView frame], [touch locationInView:self]))
    {
        self.imvChoice = (CustomImageView *) aView;
        originalPoint = aView.frame.origin;
        offsetPoint = [touch locationInView:aView];
        nIndexChoice = [self.arrCustomImageView indexOfObject:aView];
        NSLog(@"log: %@ >> %@: id: %d", NSStringFromClass([self class]),NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), nIndexChoice);
        [self bringSubviewToFront:aView];
    }
}
```

I don't think it problem because i have try add same UIImageView like as:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < [arrObject count]; i++)
{
    CustomObject *nsObj = [arrObject objectAtIndex:i];

    UIImageView *image1 = [self createUIImageView:[nsObj sName1] pointX:nsObj.pPoint1.x pointY:nsObj.pPoint1.y];
    image1.tag = i;
    [image1 setUserInteractionEnabled:FALSE];

    UIImageView *image2 = [self createUIImageView:[nsObj sName2] pointX:nsObj.pPoint2.x pointY:nsObj.pPoint2.y];
    image2.tag = i;
    [image2 setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];

    [self addSubview:image1];
    [self addSubview:image2];
    [image1 release];
    [image2 release];
}
```

it run normal :| i can't catch event when click on image1 and image2 is can.

So i have mistake? Please, explain for me! 
Thanks for all support!

Comment: where you have touchesBegan methods?

Comment: Show your code for touchesBegan method.

Comment: I have submit touchesBegan method over

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `touchesBegan` receives touches for the entire viewcontroller, not just a single uiview. if you set `userInteractionEnabled` to false the view will not be receiving any view specific events like `UITouchUpInside`.

If you want to check in you `touchesBegan` method if the user clicked on a "disabled" object you have to get the coordinates where the user touched your ViewController for example like this

```
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
```

and than check if your touchPoint is inside the rectangle of the view object you want to check

```
if (CGRectContainsPoint(cuiv, touchPoint){
    if (cuiv.userInteractionEnabled) {
     // your element is enabled, do something
    } else {
     // your element is disabled, do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: edited to reflect additional informations added to the question